# creating a view that resembles the apple app store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

So I'm creating an app at the moment and one of my views has a design that resembles the Apple app store where there are multiple icons in sections that are scrollable horizontally as well as being able to scroll vertically through the sections (Categories). Anyone with an iPhone can simply open the app store application on the device and view the featured tab to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

My question is how to achieve the design in the app store. Im assuming its a combination of multiple components such as a table view/collection view, scroll view and image views.

I don't believe there are any duplicates to this question from my research, but as always I stand corrected. Any insights or direction would be great.

Comment: I think it is simply a UITableView which contains some cell's that have an UICollectionView inside them with collectionViewCells containing the image and subtitle.

Comment: The App Store interface is done with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It's a web view.

Comment: hi matt, are you referring to the iOS version of the app store ? I didn't know that it was possible to do something like that.